# Is it possible to get MySQL to retry PK generation n times?

Tags: mysql, computed-column

I'd like to use random bytes as PK in my table and to ease the application implementation I thought about leaving the generation to the database server so collisions can be handled transparent to the app, however after testing my idea with a small key it appears that MySQL won't attempt to generate a new id on collision. Is there a way to retry the generation up to n times before failing the query, or I have to handle this in my app?

**Example setup:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test`.`new_table` (
  `id` BINARY(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (RANDOM_BYTES(1)) STORED,
  `text` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Current behaviour on duplicate key:

```sql
mysql> INSERT INTO `test`.`new_table` (`text`) VALUES ('a');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'G' for key 'new_table.PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Consider using a UUID.  (But this does not do well if you expect to have a billion rows.)

Comment: But there is still a very little chance of collision so I must handle that case, also one might be okay with more frequent collisions and the overhead caused by them in tables where inserts are rare, and in that case using 16 bytes as PK is wasteful.

Comment: @NoelNemeth I recommend you read the MySQL manual about how they encode a UUID() value. It generates a unique value, at least as well as AUTO_INCREMENT, and much better than choosing a random value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, there is no feature in MySQL to retry generating a generated column. If it generates a value that cause a constraint violation (in this case the uniqueness of a primary key), it fails, full stop. Retrying is up to you, to be implemented by writing client code and catching the error.

Rick James comments above, advising to use a UUID. This is more or less guaranteed to be unique, given the way MySQL generates them. But you can't use the UUID() function in a generated column.

```
mysql> create table mytable (id binary(16) as (uuid_to_bin(uuid())) stored );
ERROR 3763 (HY000): Expression of generated column 'id' contains a disallowed function: uuid.
```

You'll have to do it with a trigger:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id binary(16) not null primary key);

mysql> create trigger t before insert on mytable for each row set NEW.id = uuid_to_bin(uuid());

mysql> insert into mytable () values ();

mysql> select * from mytable;
+------------------------------------+
| id                                 |
+------------------------------------+
| 0x90C5291C687B11ED9147E0EAF407464A |
+------------------------------------+
```

See also:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid
- https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-uuid-support/